# How to remove box generated by input div?

Tags: html, css, search, input

I am trying to make a search box that for the submit button has a magnifying image on the left of the search box. I am using font awesome to get the image, but when I try to add that in as an input I also get a different box that says submit. I am wondering how I can remove the submit box and just have the magnifying glass. Also, any advice on how to get the magnifying glass to be inside of the search bar besides using absolute positioning would be helpful.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ouuxzs05/

HTML:

```
  <div id="searchbar">
        <div id="SearchForm"> 
            <aside id="search">
                <form action="http://example.com/search.php" method="get" onsubmit="return check_small_search_form()"> 
                <input type="text" name="search_query" id="search_query" class="search-textbox" value="" placeholder="Search Products and Categories">
                <input type="image" class="fa fa-search submit-button" src="">
                </form>
            </aside>
```

CSS:

```
#searchbar .search-textbox {
height:30px;
position:relative;
border-radius:8px;
width:200px;
margin-left:200px;
}
```

Comment: Instead of this `<input type="image" class="fa fa-search submit-button" src="">`, you can have i tag i.e '<i class="fa fa-search submit-button" ></i>'

Comment: @SjVnyk Yes it works.

Comment: @SjVnyk That does remove the search button but it also means that the magnifying glass is only an icon now, when clicked it does not submit the text to search.

Comment: @JakeP I guess we can call onClick() Method through that Icon also,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make that a `button`, then remove the border and `background`, use `translateX()` to put it over the search box, and add a right `padding` to the search box so the text doesn't go under the button.

Also removed the `outline` from your search `input` field, the button, and added a left `padding` to the search `input`

```css
#searchbar .search-textbox {
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 0 25px 0 .5em;
  outline: 0;
}

button.iconfont {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transform: translateX(-150%);
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/040e2f1f79.js"></script>

<div id="searchbar">
  <div id="SearchForm">
    <aside id="search">
      <form action="http://example.com/search.php" method="get" onsubmit="return check_small_search_form()">
        <input type="text" name="search_query" id="search_query" class="search-textbox" value="" placeholder="Search Products and Categories">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success iconfont">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
      </form>
    </aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the input type image with a button you can use following code.

```
<button><i class="fa fa-search"></button>

button{
   background:transparent;
   border:none;
   text-align:center;
   margin-left:-20px;
}
```